# How do I set the rdfs:isDefinedBy for all resources in my RDFLib graph?

Tags: python, rdflib

I would like to modify a property for all resources in my RDFLib graph which I generated from parsing a file. I then want to save the modified graph into a new file.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I am using RDFLib in Python

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from rdflib import Graph

# create an rdflib graph
g = Graph()

# fill the graph from your file
g.parse('your_rdf_file.ttl', format="turtle")

# you can then modify the contents of the graph either by accessing the graph 
# object directly (see https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_to_graphs.html) 
# or by using SPARQL `UPDATE` queries (see
# https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html 
# but there's not really enough documentation on `UPDATE`!)

# e.g 
g.update("SOME SPARQL UPDATE QUERY")

# serialize the graph to a new file
g.serialize(destination="new_file.ttl", format="turtle")
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really easy indeed. I agree there should be more information on UPDATE. Thanks anyway!